# How can I resize a box without resizing the box next to it using jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I'm trying to resize a box (orange box), but my issue is that I can ONLY resize it to the right and bottom , but I cannot resize it to the top (I only want to be able to resize it to the top).

Also after re-sizing it to the top I don't want it to resize the green box (I want the green box to be static, meaning that I don't want it to change its size, the orange box should be over it). I have tried and cannot come up with good results. Using jQuery or pure JavaScript works fine with me.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script><!-- CSS -->
  <script>
     $(function() {
        $( "#orangeBox" ).resizable();
     });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="greenBox" class="ui-widget2"> 
  <p>This is some text</p>
  <p>This is some text</p>
  <p>This is some text</p>
  <p>This is some text</p>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <div id="orangeBox" class="ui-widget"> 
  <p>This is the Orange Box</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
.ui-widget {
   background: orange;
   border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
   color: #333333;
}
.ui-widget2 {
   background: #cedc98;
   border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
   color: #333333;
}
#orangeBox { 
   width: 300px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em;
   text-align: center; margin: 0;border:2px solid black; 
}
#greenBox { 
   width: 340px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em;
   text-align: center; margin: 0; border:2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#orangeBox" ).resizable({
        handles:'n,e,s,w'  //top, right, bottom, left
    });
 });
```

working example Link in JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/hyq86sva/1/

**Edit:**

If you want it to happen on a `button` click:

```
 $(".btn").on("click", function(){
     var height = $("#orangeBox").offset().top; // get position from top
     console.log(height);
    $("#orangeBox").animate({
        height: "+="+height+'px'
    }, 1000);

 });
```

and add this in your HTML:

```
<button class="btn">Click here to resize</button>
```

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/hyq86sva/4/

Comment: Thank you!! quick question is there anyway to add a button to make the orange box go all the way to the top and a button to make it come back to it's original position??

Comment: Yes, see here.. I have added `position:absolute` and `bottom:1px` to `orangeBox`. http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/hyq86sva/2/

Comment: Your idea is great, and I went ahead and added a similar code for the button that does the opposite,.... meaning that it subtracts 250px, But if I click it again on the button, this dissappers of the screen. Any ideas how to fix that my friend.Here's my code for making the orange box come back to its original position                                                                  $(".btn2").on("click", function(){
      $("#orangeBox").animate({
            height: '-=250px'
        }, 1000);
     });

Comment: @programadorxpert: This will get the element back in old position http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/hyq86sva/4/

Comment: My friend, but there's an issue with your last answer. If I click 2 times on the "click to get back old position" button the orange box disappear :(. How to fix that? I just want it to come back to its original position and not get smaller...

Comment: Same issue with the "Click here to resize" button :(. I just want those 2 buttons to increase and come back to its original position and not to make it smaller or bigger...

Comment: @programadorxpert: Simple..set some flag and do a check http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/hyq86sva/5/

Comment: your new updates are not working when I try to resize the orange box to the top manually :( any ideas...?

Comment: It's not working at all my friend :(, I try to resize manually to the top and the whole ornage box moves to the top ....Why  is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your script :

$(function() {
        $( "#orangeBox" ).resizable({
            handles: 'n, e, s, w' 
        });
     });

Hope this helps !!